# java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: Detect premature EOF

Tags: public-key-encryption, x509

i have this code :

```
// Turn the encoded key into a real RSA public key.
// Public keys are encoded in X.509.
X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

error:

> java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException:
>   java.security.InvalidKeyException: IOException: Detect premature EOF

where is the problem?

Comment: Where did you get `keyBytes` from?

Comment: from this code: File f = new File("C:/Users/Joe/Desktop/joesaab.txt");
            try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            int theByte = 0;
            while ((theByte = fis.read()) != -1)
            {
            baos.write(theByte);
            }
            fis.close();
            

            byte[] keyBytes = baos.toByteArray();
            baos.close();
            System.out.println("pub and priv done.. Encoding started!");

Comment: Does the file exist? Have you spelled its path and name correctly? What's the content of `keyBytes`? Does it look reasonable? Or is it just an empty string or something? Where are you catching exceptions from the `try` block, and is it catching anything interesting?

Comment: file and path are correct and exist, in my code i need to encrypt a text file using RSA.. the problem is in keyspecs i think..

Comment: What is the file `joesaab.txt`? Is it the text you want to encrypt, or the key? (Java thinks you want to use it as the key.)

Comment: is a text file to be encrypted..

Comment: That'll be the problem then. You're getting the contents of the file, piping it to a `byte[]`, then trying to read it as a key. You shouldn't get the error if you replace the filename with a file containing a key in X509 format (whatever that is). Or maybe you haven't stored your key on disc, I don't know. And I also don't know what you are supposed to do with the `joesaab.txt` file.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String key) throws Exception {
      byte[] keyBytes;  
      keyBytes = (new BASE64Decoder()).decodeBuffer(key); 
      X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes); 
      KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
      PublicKey publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec); 
      return publicKey;
  }
```

this is how i turn "String key" into real rsa key(PublicKey publicKey).
maybe helps.